# How can I check for missing references in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I need to check if all the references in a project exist to avoid possible errors but I can't find anywhere how to do it in VB.NET. I can do it in VBA like this:

```
Dim vbProj As VBProject
Dim chkRef As Reference

Set vbProj = ThisWorkbook.VBProject

For Each chkRef In vbProj.References
   If chkRef.IsBroken Then
      Debug.Print chkRef.Name " reference doesn't exist!"
   End If
Next
```

To be more specific, the project references another program(BarTender) and I need to be able to open files and print them using VB.

I have it installed on my computer but if someone else ran the my project without having Bartender installed it would throw an exception of unknown data type when declaring the object variable.

How do I accomplish this in VB.NET?

Comment: Macros are gone in VS2010, you'll need to create [an add-in](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/80493a3w%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Comment: @HansPassant: Macros still exist in VS2010, no longer in VS2012.

Comment: You're right, wonder why he'd ask.

Answer (score 2):

Try enabling [`Option Strict On`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx) it will prevent late binding which should prevent your code from compiling unless all of the references are present.

From above link:

> Restricts implicit data type conversions to only widening conversions, **disallows late binding**, and disallows implicit typing that results in an Object type.

Also if you click on all files in your solution explorer you will see a References Section if you look in there. Any references with an exclamation point next to them are missing.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, but this wouldn't work on someone else's computer if they don't have the program I mentioned, that's why I need to check if the reference exists at runtime...

Comment: How is your program being installed on the other computer, it is usually the installers responsibility to install the required dependencies at the time the program is installed